# MacBook Pro 15" mid 2014 shutting down during boot (after failed macOS Catalina update)

Tags: macos, startup, install, catalina

I recently updated my Mac to macOS Catalina and it was going well until I installed the recent update and got stuck in the restarting installation process because there wasn't enough free space to finish the update.

What I tried to fix this includes:

- using startup disk utility to select my disk to reboot from it (I read that this should bypass the installation and let me log in to my Mac to free some space before redoing the update) but it didn't work.
- holding Cmd + R while restarting to get access to the repair utility where I deleted my Boot Camp partition where windows was installed.

What's happening now is that when I'm trying to log in a progress bar appears and after reaching a little more than halfway my Mac suddenly shuts down. So I've now tried:

- resetting the SMC (System Management Controller)
- resetting the NVRAM (Non Volatile Random Access Memory)
- mounting and repairing my volume (but it didn't).

I can mount my disk and open terminal to navigate on it, so I was thinking that maybe the update was preventing my Mac from booting and that deleting the files that are being launched to perform the update when booting would probably kill the process but I wanted to share my problem before doing this and risking to erase important filesystem files that could corrupt my drive.

All my data is on this Mac and reinstalling the macOS is my last resort.

What else should I try to resolve this?

Comment: Got exactly the same problem with my mid-2014 MacBook Pro 13”. Try to solve with Apple support, no success. Now, if I try reinstall the OS with the disc utility app in restore mode, the utility don’t let install the OS, but it see my HD. All those trouble with the last Catalina update, apparently there was not enough space on my hard drive to complete the installation, the update script should have validate the free space before the it begin the installation, very bad conception. Now, I think that the only solution will be a good old backup, format reinstall...hope it will work...